# Pass a json object to the call of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to pass the json `item`, to a `details()` function. The call of the function is through the onclick event of a text string that is printed in the document with jquery. But he throws me an error.

This is a summary of the code:

```
var item = {/*...*/}; //json object
var html = '<a onclick="userListDetails('+item+')" >Detalles</a>';

$('#panel').append(html);
```

Throw error when launching the function

Comment: Please share your details function

Comment: I have only one console.log () and the rest commented, but it still does not work. I think something comes out when the parameter passes.

Comment: I have tried to pass the function without parameters. And the call is done well, too, and the json is printed from outside the function and the json also works well.

Comment: is this inside your document.ready ?

Comment: Since 'item' is declared in the outer scope, you could just use 'item' inside your function.

Comment: Note that there is no JSON in the code shown, your `item` is just an object. ([There ain't no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/))

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use string concatenation in `userListDetails('+item+')`. Simply use `userListDetails(item)`. 
Try the following:

```js
var item = {first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"}; //json object
var html = "<a onclick='userListDetails(item)' >Detalles</a>";

$('#panel').append(html);
function userListDetails(json){ 
  console.log(json);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because javascript will try to convert `item` to a string, giving something like `[Object object]` and your html will end up as

`<a onclick="userListDetails([Object object])">Detalles</a>`

...which won't work. There's two approaches you can take here:

1) Make `item` global object, and then reference it by name:

```
window.item = { ... }; //some object in global scope
$('#panel').append("<a onclick="userListDetails(item)">Detalles</a>);
```

Like `userListDetails`, `item` is in global scope so you can access it from HTML.

2) Add a click listener in javascript instead of HTML

```
var item = { ... }; //some object
var $detailLink = $("<a>Detalles</a>");
$('#panel').append( $detailLink );

$detailLink.on("click", function() {
    userListDetails( item );
});
```

Overall I prefer the second way - it's a lot more flexible and doesn't clutter up the global scope.

Comment: Your first example won't work. You're using quotation marks the wrong way. Second way also doesn't work in this context, unless it's a global object which it most likely isn't as it's being binded into the function.

Comment: if it's a global variable, why do you send it a parameter? the function userListDetails will be able to access it anyway

Comment: Sure - just allows you to call `userListDetails()` with other parameters from other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by generating an identifier for `<a>`. Then insert in the document and then treat the event click by the identifier:

```
var index = 'unique_id_' + index; //Index is generate by a query.
var json = jsonQuery; //jsonQuery is generate by a query.
var html = '<a id="'+index +'" ></a>';
$("#panel").append(html);
$("#"+index ).on("click",function(){
    /* code */
});
```